# Hand bone bends lower arm but there is no weight, how I fix that?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, weight-painting

I have a problem which I don't know what cause it. When I rotate hand bone lower arm mesh bends with hand (which is not realistic).

I look weight painting but there is no problem (I think).

I tried painting and subtracting weight but there is no change.

I tried changing bones location but nothing change.

I apply transform, scale and rotation.

I recalculate the normals.

How to fix that?

I hope you understand, thanks!

Here is the blend file:
[image]

Photos:

[image: Problem]

[image: Hand weight paint 1]

[image: Hand weight paint 2]

[image: Trying weight painting]

Comment: The arm bone may be set to non-deforming, and there may be weights that are too small to see with colors, which are normalized to a much larger number in the absence of the arm weights thus ignored.  Maybe you could provide a file so we could check if that was the case before answering, or see if there's some other reason?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I added the blend file. I use rigify not my bones, I think there is no non-deforming bones. I subtract the all arm weight and I saw there is hand weight on arm than I subtract it too than I repaint them but nothing change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your weights are ok.  But you have all of your bones set up as multiple segment bendy bones.  You can see this by enabling bendy bone display in properties/object/viewport display/display as:

[image]

Your arm is not bending because of any weights to the hand, but because the hand is the outro bone of the bendy bone forearm.

If you don't want this to happen, you can set the segment length of the forearm to 1 in properties/bone/bendy bones, or you can set a custom end handle in the same section to prevent the arm from bending into the hand (bending into some other bone instead.)

Comment: Wow, thats really helpful! I fix the problem thanks!